# Javascript: How can an object store a reference to another object's method, and call it "remotely"?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, reference, eval

So, I got two objects, a and b. Now, I want to pass one of b's methods to the a object, wich should store it. Let's call that method b.met:

```
b.met=function(){
    alert(this.txt);
}
```

Now, I want to call b.met from a. The following code doesn't work, since a.met is a clone of b.met inside the scope of a:

```
a.met=b.met;
a.met(); //Executes in the 'a' scope!
```

The only way I found, by now, is to save the method's name in a string and use it in an eval statement:

```
a.toCall='b.met';
eval(a.toCall+'();');
```

Since everyone says you should avoid using eval... what other possibilities are there?

---

EDIT - see in comments: So I changed my code from:

```
a:{
    processes:[],
    spawnProcess:function(type,id,closeFn){
    var closeFn=closeFn || 'function(){}';
    this.processes.push({type:type,id:id,closeFn:closeFn});
}
```

to:

```
a:{
    processes:[],
    spawnProcess:function(type,id,closeFn){
    var closeFn=function(){closeFn()} || 'function(){}';
    this.processes.push({type:type,id:id,closeFn:function(){closeFn()}});
}
```

When executing the following code, I get a too much recursion error:

```
a.spawnProcess('','',b.met);
a.processes[0].closeFn();
```

Comment: You are looking for [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) and [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/call).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your storing a reference to a function. A function is just a function. It get's it's definition for `this` based on the calling context.

So if you store `a.met = b.met` and then call `a.met()` inside that function `this === a`

Read up [at the JavaScript garden about `this`](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this)

What you want to do is store the function and the context to call it in.

This can be done either as

```
a.met = function() {
  b.met();
}
```

or

`a.met = b.met.bind(b);`

[`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) requires ES5. Recommended cross browser alternatives include [`_.bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind) and [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

**Edit**

You need to change

`a.spawnProcess('','',b.met);`

to

```
a.spawnProcess('','', function() {
    b.met();
});
```

You probably also want this instead

```
a: {
    processes: [],
    spawnProcess: function(type, id, closeFn) {
        this.processes.push({
            type: type,
            id: id,
            closeFn: closeFn || function() {}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try the .bind method yet, but I tried the other solution you gave me, and it doesn't work for what I'm trying to do... I put the code into the bottom of my question, maybe you could take a look?

Comment: @Alex btw emulating processes in javascript is a bad idea. Use web workers. (JavaScript is single threaded)

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution:

```
a.met = function() { b.met(); };
```

or using `.bind` (see [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)), same semantic:

```
a.met = b.met.bind(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your functions are many and they have arguments you can also do this

```
function B() {
    this.x = "I am b";
}

function A() {
    this.x = "I am A";
}

B.prototype.met = function() {
    alert(this.x);
}

A.prototype.met = B.prototype.met;
```

You can update A.prototype with functions that you need from B.prototype.